# Lambda function scale hardware analogue

Tags: aws-lambda

Probably I am not understanding lambda correctly and will get downvoted but what I am interested is :what is hardware cpu analogue of 128/256 etc if it was indipendent/dedicated hardware or ec2 instance.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If Lambda functions run on dedicated hardware or virtual machines?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark, I'll try to give an example: If 1ghz cpu machine on 128 ram working on a task with 100% cpu for 5 minutes ... how long does it take for lambda function to do the same task , I mean there must be some comparison... all we know it scales if you add more ram ... not much about the cpu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Amazon's response in [this forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=614558):

> ...we currently use instances comparable to those of a compute optimized
>   ec2 instance. The CPU share dedicated to a function is based off of
>   the fraction of its allocated memory, per each of the two cores. For
>   example, an instance with ~ 3 GB memory available for lambda functions
>   where each function can have up to 1 GB memory means at most you can
>   utilize ~ 1/3 * 2 cores = 2/3 of the CPU. The details may be revisited
>   in the future, but that is the fractional nature of our usage model.